# Getting 404 File Not Found on Apache 2.4, FastCGI and Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: fastcgi, hhvm

My first step was install HHVM following this guide: https://github.com/facebook/hhvm/wiki/Prebuilt-packages-on-Ubuntu-14.04

Then i run the script with the command: ´sudo /usr/share/hhvm/install_fastcgi.sh

Then i test if hhvm was installed with command ´php -v´ and the output is OK, says that HIPHOP VM is runing.

The problem arrives when i try to access to a PHP file, Apache always return 404 error. In the other hand html files and static files works good. I only receive 404 error with php files.

I search on Google and found many people with same issue but no solutions. Perhaps someone can help.

Comment: I think this might be better off on superuser.com

Comment: Are you giving the url of the php page or just the directory & trying to load index.php

Comment: Yes,i am giving the url of php page

Comment: a html page in the same directory doesnt give you a 404 error?